# Getting Error: Missing close quote character (") when reading table after using BigQueryUpsertTableOperator from GCS bucket

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, directed-acyclic-graphs, external-tables

I have a task that reads all files from a specific bucket path. All these files follow the same schema/format, and only difference is data is from each day so the file name is blahblah-(date).csv. I am using a BigQueryUpsertTableOperator task to wildcard these files and bring them all into the the same external table. The problem I am running into is when trying to query this table in bigquery I recieve this error:

`Error while reading table: irm-eap-edp-ingestion-nonprod.route4me.routes_external, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 44648. Error: Missing close quote character ("). File: gs://ingestion-bucket/data/blahblah-2023-06-28.csv`

Here specifying that there is something wrong with the file from this date. I have downloaded this specific file and checked it on google sheets seeing if there were any open quotes and have found that someone inputting data with month'day `BLR 28th June'23 (Original Route: XN)`. So this is the ' quote that is being opened but then not closed. I believe this is the problem that is occuring.

How can I go about editing these files automatically to incase specific columns in full quote? Or avoid quotes causing this problem.

I have specified "allowQuotedNewlines": True, in my task now. As i was having this problem beforehand without it. However still running into this problem.

This is my DAG task currently to create the external tables from the gcs bucket.

```
# Create external tables
    create_external_table = BigQueryUpsertTableOperator(
        task_id=f"create_external_{TABLE}_table",
        dataset_id=DATASET,
        project_id=INGESTION_PROJECT_ID,
        table_resource={
            "tableReference": {"tableId": f"{TABLE}_external"},
            "externalDataConfiguration": {
                "sourceFormat": "CSV",
                "allowQuotedNewlines": True,
                "autodetect": True,
                "sourceUris": [f"gs://{ARCHIVE_BUCKET}/{DATASET}_data/*.csv"],
            },
            "labels": labeler.get_labels_bigquery_table_v2(
                target_project=INGESTION_PROJECT_ID,
                target_dataset=DATASET,
                target_table=f"{TABLE}_external",
            ),
        },
    )
```

EDIT: for some reason I have downloaded the file itself and tried to manually create a table with it by uploading.Tried creating table and it failed. Then I selected Allow quotes new lines in the advanced settings and the table was created fine and I am able to query it. Am i not using the correct flag in my task or is it even working? ("allowQuotedNewlines": True,)

Comment: From the error  it seems like the error is due to the missing close quote character ("). `allowQuotedNewlines` indicates whether to allow quoted data sections that contain newline characters in a CSV file.Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#troubleshoot_parsing_errors) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew I have already enabled the option for allowQuotedNewLines to be true still running into error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I am using the wrong "allowQuotedNewlines" option instead it should be "allow_quoted_newlines" the process is now working as intended.